# How to async append hidden field to form on submit without jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api, form-submit

I have this small piece of jQuery code which works just fine. In one of my project I need to get rid of jQuery so I need to re-write this piece of code to vanilla js.
The form:

```
<form action="/document-link/" method="POST" class="form">
    <input type="text" name="foo" value=""></input>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The script:

```
$('.form').each(function() {
    var frm = this;
    $(frm).bind('submit', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/libs/form-check.php',
            data: { value: $('input[name="foo"]', frm).val() },
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $(frm).append('<input type="hidden" name="approval" value="' + data + '" />');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The new way:

```
const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.form');
forms.forEach(function(frm) {
    frm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        // get ajax (XMLHttpRequest? fetch?) answer and create hidden field
    },false);
});
```

The form component is working the old fashion way:

1. submit
2. server-side validate fields
3. if invalid - return whole page with form extended for error classes
4. if valid
   a) reload whole page without form but with the message
   b) redirect page to custom page (on backend user has the ability to set the answer page)

Therefore I need to submit the whole form without ajax. I know the `submit` event is fired immediatelly and I need to wait for async fetch to wait but this is the part where I am completely lost.

EDIT:

Tried this dirty hack with triggering click on submit button. Ugly but works.

```
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  const approval = form.querySelector('[name="approval"]');
  if(!approval) { // check if hidden field in DOM, if not fetch one
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the submission
    const thisForm = this; // save the DOM element
    fetch('/libs/form-check.php', { value: this.foo.value })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const ele = document.createElement("input"); // or have the hidden field in the form already
        ele.name = "approval";
        ele.type = "hidden";
        ele.value = data; // or data.approval if you have { "approval"="yes" } as return value
        thisForm.appendChild(ele);
        thisForm.querySelector('[type="submit"]').click(); // submit form again
        // thisForm.submit(); // this only reloads page - try http://replit.com/@5ulo/Form#index.php
      })
  }
})
```

Comment: What does `/libs/form-check.php` actually do?

Comment: Also submit the form and redirect on the server. Problem solved

Comment: `form-check.php` returns some string value which is added to the form as a hidden field and submitted to the server together with all form fields. Problem is the `submit` event listener does not wait for fetch and the form is submitted without the hidden field.